# CentOS 5 installation method

Tags: linux, centos

I am tyring to install [CentOS-5.3](http://archive.kernel.org/centos-vault/5.3/isos/i386/), don't ask why I just need. (I picked CentOS-5.3-i386-netinstall.iso), on VMware, but after a few steps, I get this:

[image]

What is this? I don't think I need this how to skip over it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You selected the net install option so will need to specify the HTTP option and configure your TCP/IP connection.

The name of the server should be something like this:

```
Website: /centos/5.3/os/i386     
CentOS directory: /centos/5/os/i386
```

[Source](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/centos-netinstall-network-installation/)

Comment: The mirror site `mirror.centos.org` does not point to any end of life packages.  The original poster will be required to use the CentOS vault: `http://vault.centos.org/5.3/os/i386/`

Comment: @GracefulRestart You are right, pleas post as answer

Comment: @kemotep fix to: `vault.centos.org/5.3/os/i386` and to `/centos/5.3/os/i386`